# Compare two lists value-wise in Python

Tags: python, list, compare

For example, `a = [1,1,3,4]` and `b = [3,1,4,1]` and I want a results **matched**.
If one has a unique value that the other list doesn't have, then return **unmatched**

Comment: I'll answer this question, but you really need to do research before posting a question.

Comment: `'matched' if a == b else 'unmatched'`

Comment: @Alexander That won't work because the arrays might be ordered differently.

Comment: If order does not matter (i.e. two lists with the same items but arranged in different order are considered to be equal), then use: `'matched' if sorted(a) == sorted(b) else 'unmatched'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have 2 list

```
x = ['3', '1']
y = ['1', '3']
```

**Solution-1:**

You can simply check whether the multisets with the elements of x and y are equal:

```
import collections

collections.Counter(x) == collections.Counter(y)
```

This requires the elements to be hashable; runtime will be in O(n), where n is the size of the lists.

**Solution-2:**

If the elements are also unique, you can also convert to sets (same asymptotic runtime, may be a little bit faster in practice):

```
set(x) == set(y)
```

**Solution-3:**

If the elements are neither hashable nor sortable you can use the following helper function. Note that it will be quite slow (O(n²)) and should generally not be used outside of the esoteric case of unhashable and unsortable elements.

```
def equal_ignore_order(a, b):
    """ Use only when elements are neither hashable nor sortable! """
    unmatched = list(b)
    for element in a:
        try:
            unmatched.remove(element)
        except ValueError:
            return False
    return not unmatched
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the order of elements you can do this:

```py
def compare(a, b):
    return 'matched' if sorted(a) == sorted(b) else 'unmatched'

a = [1,1,3,4]
b = [3,1,4,1]
print(compare(a, b))

>>> 'matched'
```

Comment: This is always `True` since `.sort()` is in-place and returns `None`

Comment: @Chris_Rands true, updated.

Answer (score 0):

Per Alexander:

```
result = 'matched' if a == b else 'unmatched'
print(result)
```

Comment: `zip(*(a,b))` -> `zip(a,b)` anyway, this seems to just be re-implementing `list.__eq__`, which isn't what the OP wants, note, it gives unmatched for the op's `a` and `b` example